# Error when installing go-oci8

Tags: oracle, gcc, go, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I get this error when trying to install go-oci8.

```
bueno@felipe-cb:~/devel/go/src/github.com/mattn/go-oci8$ go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8
# github.com/mattn/go-oci8
gcc: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Information that might help:

GCC Version:

```
bueno@felipe-cb:~/devel/go/src/github.com/mattn/go-oci8$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.7.2-5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
```

Oracle Home:

```
bueno@felipe-cb:~/devel/go/src/github.com/mattn/go-oci8$ ls -la $ORACLE_HOME
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Fev 21 12:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 21 07:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 07:07 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Fev 21 12:50 include -> /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 07:07 lib
```

Include dir:

```
bueno@felipe-cb:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/include$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/include 
bueno@felipe-cb:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/include$ ls -la
total 1676
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jan 21 07:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jan 21 07:07 ..
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 188312 Mai 24  2013 oci.h
...
```

Lib dir:

```
bueno@felipe-cb:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/include$ cd $ORACLE_HOME/lib
bueno@felipe-cb:/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib$ ls -la
total 212884
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 Jan 21 07:07 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.12.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55453863 Mai 24  2013 libclntsh.so.12.1
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
  Link for the issue on Github - https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/issues/19

Update Feb 24:

```
bueno@felipe-cb:~$ go version
go version go1.2 linux/amd64
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hey @refi64. I never solved this problem =/